# Convert a column in a list to number, keeping other columns unchanged

Tags: python, list

I have a list like below. I want to replace the number in the list to integer which is currently in a form of string in single quotes `'8'`.

Once replaced with the number, want to sort on that number in a list.

```
[['8', '/opt/sis/local/ad'], ['327912', '/opt/sis/local/bd'], ['20180', '/opt/sis/local/cd'], ['40', '/opt/sis/local/dd'], ['1464', '/opt/sis/local/ed'], ['32', '/opt/sis/local/fd'], ['3803092', '/opt/sis/local/gd'], ['34930968', '/opt/sis/local/hd'], ['3095500', '/opt/sis/local/id-inventory']]
```

I'm doing this to find the top 4 directories that are consuming more space.

Comment: You're looking for `int` and `list.sort`.

Comment: you don't need to convert to int just use `l.sort(key = lambda x : int(x[0]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first transpose it (ie change rows to columns)

```
columns = zip(*my_2d_list)
```

then change the first column

```
columns[0] = [int(n) for n in columns[0]]
```

and finally zip it back to your original list

```
my_2d_list = zip(*columns)
```

then just sort it

```
sorted(my_2d_list,reverse=True)[:4] # 4 biggest numbers ... at least it should be
```

however it is probably more wise to just do

```
 sorted(my_original_list,key=lambda x: int(x[0]),reverse=True)[:4]
```

as mentioned by @PadraicCunningham (and jon sharp)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much guys! really made my day. I'm liking python :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [[int(x[0]), x[1]] for x in data]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: because of how sorting works with lists/tuples I dont think you need the key argument +1 though as this is nice and clean